# What's the header file of gluLookAt in Qt?

Tags: qt, opengl

I got some code for using OpenGL in Qt. And when I run it I got error as below:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NeHe6\NeHe6-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug\..\NeHe6\nehewidget.cpp:54: error: 'gluLookAt' was not declared in this scope
```

It seems the header is missing. And the current headers are:

```
#include "nehewidget.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include <qtopengl\QtOpenGL>
```

And "nehewidget.h" contains below headers:

```
#include <qtopengl\QGLWidget>
#include <QTimer>
```

Could anyone tell me what is the missing header?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it cant find the libraries you need.  Check your installation of the openGL helper libraries.  Specifically it is looking for GLU.  You need to add it to your linker options, for example `-lGLU`.  You then need to include it your code:

```
#include <GL/glu.h>
```

Examples of linking and including GLU (and GLUT) across multiple platforms can be found [here](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/courses/eecs487/glut-howto/)

Comment: Sorry, but GLU **not** included in GLUT. They're completely unrelated libraries. GLU usually comes as an extra library on most systems.

Comment: Next issue: So far you're only telling to include the GLU headers. But this doesn't add the GLU library to the program. For this, the library must be added to the linker options.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the end of the .pro file and you add the lib to your project:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lGLU
```

Comment: Not for Windows.